# High Chart arearange graph not showing in gray scale PDF

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, highcharts, itext

I have a high chart area range graph.When i convert it to gray scale PDF(by converting color PDF) using itextsharp  the graph is not showing .What will be the reason?

I have converted by html to color PDF using evo pdf and it is working fine.when i convert this pdf to gray scale using itext sharp it is not showing high chart area graph.

```
PdfContentToGrayscaleConverter grayScaleConverter = new PdfContentToGrayscaleConverter();

            reader = new PdfReader(originalFileFullPath);

            using (FileStream fsOutput = new FileStream(grayFileFullPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite))
            {
                document = new iTextSharp.text.Document(reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1));
                writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, fsOutput);

                document.Open();
                PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;

                int numberOfPages = reader.NumberOfPages;

                for (int pageNumber = 1; pageNumber <= numberOfPages; pageNumber++)
                {
                    Rectangle pageSizeWithRotation = reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(pageNumber);

                    document.SetPageSize(pageSizeWithRotation);
                    document.NewPage();

                    // >>> CONVERT CURRENT PAGE TO GRAYSCALE
                    grayScaleConverter.Convert(reader, pageNumber);
                    // <<<<

                    PdfImportedPage pip = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, pageNumber);

                    if (pageSizeWithRotation.Rotation == 90 || pageSizeWithRotation.Rotation == 270)
                    {
                        cb.AddTemplate(pip, 0, -1f, 1f, 0, 0, pageSizeWithRotation.Height);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cb.AddTemplate(pip, 1f, 0, 0, 1f, 0, 0);
                    }
                }

                if (document != null)
                {
                    document.Close(); document.Dispose(); document = null;
                }
                if (writer != null)
                {
                    writer.Close(); writer.Dispose(); writer = null;
                }
                if (reader != null)
                {
                    reader.Close(); reader.Dispose(); reader = null;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Please list things you've tried out so far with code snippet.

Comment: You say: *"When I convert it to gray scale PDF using iTextSharp..."* How are you doing that? Surely you don't expect an answer based on so little information!

Comment: @BrunoLowagie  I have edited my question

Comment: [1] You're doing it wrong: using `Document`/`PdfWriter`/`PdfImportedPage` throws away all interactivity. You should use `PdfStamper` instead. [2] You are leaving out the most important part of the code `PdfContentToGrayscaleConverter` is not an iTextSharp class. We have no clue what you're doing in the `Convert()` method. You're probably throwing away or (more likely) corrupting plenty of content in that class.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie can you please provide me a sample?

Comment: @BrunoLowagie PdfContentToGrayscaleConverter : using iTextSharp.text.pdf.converter

Comment: [1.] No, I can't provide a sample. [2.] There is no `iTextSharp.text.pdf.converter` package in the **official iTextSharp**: https://github.com/itext/itextsharp/tree/master/src/core/iTextSharp/text/pdf Maybe you're using some third party version.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie using iTextSharp.extended

Comment: @James Is this the iTextSharp.extended you mentioned? https://itextsharpextended.codeplex.com/ Guessing from the filename, I'd say it's an add-on for iTextSharp 5.4.4, licensed GPLv2 (iTextSharp proper is AGPL). This is a blogpost by the developer of iTextSharp.extended: http://habjan.blogspot.be/2013/09/proof-of-concept-converting-pdf-files.html

Comment: AGPLv3 and GPLv2 are not compatible. Please throw away that version of iTextSharp. It's not an official version. iText Group doesn't take any responsability for it and questions about unofficial version are ignored (especially if they violate some of the basic open source compatibility rules).